# Why is my eventSources null? using calendarDemo

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, fullcalendar

Below is my controller and I'm using the calendar.js directive from github
 with this html code:

My webpage is filled with errors:

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined because eventSources is null.

WHY IS IT NULL!?

```
/*jshint sub:true*/
'use strict';
angular.module('com.module.schedule')
  .controller('EventsCtrl',['$scope',function ($scope, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams, CoreService, Event, gettextCatalog) {

        function CalendarCtrl($scope,$compile,uiCalendarConfig) {
            var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getDate();
            var m = date.getMonth();
            var y = date.getFullYear();

            $scope.changeTo = 'Hungarian';

            /* event source that pulls from google.com */
            $scope.eventSource = {
                url: "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic",
                className: 'gcal-event',           // an option!
                currentTimezone: 'America/Chicago' // an option!
            };

            /* event source that contains custom events on the scope */
            $scope.events = [
                {title: 'All Day Event',start: new Date(y, m, 1)},
                {title: 'Long Event',start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),end: new Date(y, m, d - 2)},
                {id: 999,title: 'Repeating Event',start: new Date(y, m, d - 3, 16, 0),allDay: false},
                {id: 999,title: 'Repeating Event',start: new Date(y, m, d + 4, 16, 0),allDay: false},
                {title: 'Birthday Party',start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),allDay: false},
                {title: 'Click for Google',start: new Date(y, m, 28),end: new Date(y, m, 29),url: 'http://google.com/'}
            ];



            /* event source that calls a function on every view switch */
            $scope.eventsF = function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
                var s = new Date(start).getTime() / 1000;
                var e = new Date(end).getTime() / 1000;
                var m = new Date(start).getMonth();
                var events = [{title: 'Feed Me ' + m,start: s + (50000),end: s + (100000),allDay: false, className: ['customFeed']}];
                callback(events);
            };


            /* event sources array*/
            $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events,$scope.eventSource, $scope.eventsF];
            $scope.eventSources2 = [$scope.calEventsExt, $scope.eventsF, $scope.events];
        }

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check two things:

1 - that your calendar control is under the scope of the EventsCtrl.

Should be something like:

```
<div ng-controler="EventsCtrl">
    <div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar"  ng-model="eventSources"></div> 
</div>
```

2 - You have in your Controller the config of the calendar.

So if you define:

```
<div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" ng-model="eventSources"></div>
```

Then in your controler should exists the object uiConfig.calendar with its configuration:

```
$scope.uiConfig = {
      calendar:{
        height: 450,
        editable: true,
        header:{
          left: 'title',
          center: '',
          right: 'today prev,next'
        },
        eventClick: $scope.alertOnEventClick,
        eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
        eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,
        eventRender: $scope.eventRender
      }
    };
```